# Autoencoder with multiple input and output with multiple losses?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have tried to implement a research paper which have multiple input and multiple output images with multiple losses as below code but some where I made the mistake and loss is not minimizing and generated or output images does not have any effect with respect to different epoch. You may trace out the training function, I am confident for model architecture implementation but I am not sure for the training. Is the add_loss function is need to provide?

The code is already present in github but I want that tensorflow, so I made the above code you can see given network in following image:[Network to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzAow.png) and there internal component defined as: [internal functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mUAO.png) you can see there pytorch code by following link: https://github.com/chosj95/MIMO-Unet

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose
from data_loader import DataLoader
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, LeakyReLU, UpSampling2D


class MIMO_Model():
    def __init__(self):
        # Input shape
        self.img_rows = 256
        self.img_cols = 256
        self.channels = 3
        self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
        self.real_path = "C:\\DataSets\\GOPRO\\"
        self.model_folder = "MIMO_Models"
        self.data_path = "data_folder"
        self.output_image = "output\\images"
        path1 = self.real_path + self.model_folder
        path2 = self.real_path + self.output_image
        try:
            os.makedirs(path1)
        except OSError as error:
            print(error)
        try:
            os.makedirs(path2)
        except OSError as error:
            print(error)

        self.dataset_name = self.data_path
        self.data_loader = DataLoader(dataset_name=self.dataset_name, img_res=(self.img_rows, self.img_cols))
        # Number of filters in the first layer of G and D
        self.gf = 32
        self.df = 32

        # Build the generator
        self.models = self.build_generator
        self.generator1 = self.models[0]
        self.generator2 = self.models[1]
        self.generator3 = self.models[2]
        # Input images and their conditioning images
        img_A = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
        img_B = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

        # By conditioning on B generate a fake version of A
        fake_A1 = self.generator1(img_B)
        fake_A2 = self.generator2(img_B)
        fake_A3 = self.generator3(img_B)
        self.combined1 = Model(inputs=img_B, outputs=fake_A1)
        self.combined2 = Model(inputs=img_B, outputs=fake_A2)
        self.combined3 = Model(inputs=img_B, outputs=fake_A3)

    def convolutionLayer(self, layer_input, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=True, bn=False):
        d= Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=stride, padding='same', use_bias=bias)(layer_input)
        if relu:
            d = ReLU()(d)
        if bn:
            d = BatchNormalization()(d)
        return d

    def residualBlocks(self, layer_input, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1):
        d = self.convolutionLayer(layer_input, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, relu=True)
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, relu=False)
        return d

    def featureAttention(self, layer_input, scm_out, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=True, bn=False, tran=False,
                         bias=True):
        x1 = layer_input * scm_out
        x1 = self.convolutionLayer(x1, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=False)
        out = x1 + layer_input
        return out

    def SCM_Block(self, layer_input, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=True, bn=False, tran=False, bias=True):
        d = self.convolutionLayer(layer_input, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, relu=True)
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size - 2, stride=stride, relu=True)
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, relu=True)
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size - 2, stride=stride, relu=True)
        d = Concatenate()([layer_input, d])
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size - 2, stride=stride, relu=True)
        return d

    def AFF1_Block(self, a, b, c, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=True, bn=False, tran=False, bias=True):
        a = tf.image.resize(a, [256, 256])
        b = tf.image.resize(b, [256, 256])
        c = tf.image.resize(c, [256, 256])
        d = Concatenate()([a, b, c])
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=1, stride=1, relu=True)
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=False)
        return d

    def AFF2_Block(self, a, b, c, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=True, bn=False, tran=False, bias=True):
        a = tf.image.resize(a, [128, 128])
        b = tf.image.resize(b, [128, 128])
        c = tf.image.resize(c, [128, 128])
        d = Concatenate()([a, b, c])
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=1, stride=1, relu=True)
        d = self.convolutionLayer(d, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, relu=False)
        return d

    def eBlock(self, layer_input, filters, num_res=8):
        e = layer_input
        for num1 in range(num_res):
            e = self.residualBlocks(e, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        return e

    def dBlock(self, layer_input, filters, num_res=8):
        d = layer_input
        for num1 in range(num_res):
            d = self.residualBlocks(d, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        return d

    @property
    def build_generator(self):
        """U-Net Generator"""
        # Input Image
        b1 = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
        b2 = tf.image.resize(b1, [128, 128])
        b3 = tf.image.resize(b2, [64, 64])
        # Downsampling Level 1
        e1 = self.eBlock(b1, self.gf)
        # Downsampling Level 2
        e2 = Conv2D(self.gf * 2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(e1)
        b_scm2 = self.SCM_Block(b2, self.gf * 2)
        e2 = self.featureAttention(e2, b_scm2, self.gf * 2)
        e2 = self.eBlock(e2, self.gf * 2)
        # Downsampling Level 3
        e3 = Conv2D(self.gf * 4, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(e2)
        b_scm3 = self.SCM_Block(b3, self.gf * 4)
        e3 = self.featureAttention(e3, b_scm3, self.gf * 4)
        e3 = self.eBlock(e3, self.gf * 4)

        # Asymmetric Feature Fusion
        a1 = self.AFF1_Block(e1, e2, e3, self.gf)
        a2 = self.AFF2_Block(e1, e2, e3, self.gf * 2)

        # Upsampling Level 3
        d3 = self.dBlock(e3, self.gf * 4)
        S3 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(d3)
        S3 = b3 + S3
        d3 = Conv2DTranspose(self.gf * 4, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(d3)
        model3 = Model(b1, S3)
        # Upsampling Level 2
        d2 = Concatenate()([a2, d3])
        d2 = self.dBlock(d2, self.gf * 2)
        S2 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(d2)
        S2 = b2 + S2
        d2 = Conv2DTranspose(self.gf * 2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(d2)
        model2 = Model(b1, S2)
        # Upsampling Level 1
        d1 = Concatenate()([a1, d2])
        d1 = self.dBlock(d1, self.gf)
        S1 = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(d1)
        S1 = b1 + S1
        model1 = Model(b1, S1)
        return model1, model2, model3

    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    # Prepare the metrics.
    train_acc_metric = keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    val_acc_metric = keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, img_A, img_B, optimizer, a, b, c):
        img_A2 = tf.image.resize(img_A, [128, 128])
        img_A3 = tf.image.resize(img_A, [64, 64])
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
            logits1 = self.combined1(img_B, training=True)
            loss_value1 = self.loss_fn(img_A, logits1)
            loss_value1 = tf.cast(loss_value1, tf.float64)
            a = tf.cast(a, tf.float64)
            loss_value1 = loss_value1 + a * 0.1
        grads1 = tape1.gradient(loss_value1, self.combined1.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, self.combined1.trainable_weights))
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
            logits2 = self.combined2(img_B, training=True)
            loss_value2 = self.loss_fn(img_A2, logits2)
            loss_value2 = tf.cast(loss_value2, tf.float64)
            b = tf.cast(b, tf.float64)
            loss_value2 = loss_value2 + b * 0.1
        grads2 = tape2.gradient(loss_value2, self.combined2.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, self.combined2.trainable_weights))
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape3:
            logits3 = self.combined3(img_B, training=True)
            loss_value3 = self.loss_fn(img_A3, logits3)
            loss_value3 = tf.cast(loss_value3, tf.float64)
            c = tf.cast(c, tf.float64)
            loss_value3 = loss_value3 + c * 0.1
        grads3 = tape3.gradient(loss_value3, self.combined3.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads3, self.combined3.trainable_weights))
        loss_value = (loss_value1 + loss_value2 + loss_value3) / 3
        self.train_acc_metric.update_state(img_A, logits1)
        self.train_acc_metric.update_state(img_A2, logits2)
        self.train_acc_metric.update_state(img_A3, logits3)
        loss_value = tf.cast(loss_value, tf.float64)
        b = tf.cast(b, tf.float64)
        loss_value = (loss_value + b * 0.1) / 2
        return [loss_value1, loss_value2, loss_value3, loss_value]

    def train(self, epochs, batch_size=1, sample_interval=50):
        global optimizer
        LAMBDA = 0.1
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            if epoch % 500 == 0:
                optimizer = Adam(0.0001, 0.5)
            for batch_i, (img_A, img_B) in enumerate(self.data_loader.load_batch(batch_size)):
                a = 0
                b = 0
                c = 0
                if batch_i > 0:
                    fake_A1 = self.generator1.predict(img_B)
                    fake_A2 = self.generator2.predict(img_B)
                    fake_A3 = self.generator3.predict(img_B)
                    img_A2 = tf.image.resize(img_A, [128, 128])
                    img_A3 = tf.image.resize(img_A, [64, 64])
                    fake_A1 = np.fft.fft2(fake_A1)
                    fake_A2 = np.fft.fft2(fake_A2)
                    fake_A3 = np.fft.fft2(fake_A3)
                    img_A1 = np.fft.fft2(img_A)
                    img_A2 = np.fft.fft2(img_A2)
                    img_A3 = np.fft.fft2(img_A3)
                    a = self.loss_fn(img_A1, fake_A1)
                    b = self.loss_fn(img_A2, fake_A2)
                    c = self.loss_fn(img_A3, fake_A3)
                loss_value = self.train_step(img_A, img_B, optimizer, a, b, c)
                elapsed_time = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
                print("[Epoch %d/%d] [Batch %d/%d] [loss at level1: %f] [loss at level2: %f] [loss at level3: %f] [Normalized loss: %f] time: %s" % (
                    epoch, epochs, batch_i, self.data_loader.n_batches, float(loss_value[0]), float(loss_value[1]),
                    float(loss_value[2]), float(loss_value[3]), elapsed_time))
                
            # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
            train_acc = self.train_acc_metric.result()
            print("Training acc over epoch:%d, %.4f" % (epoch, float(train_acc),))
            self.train_acc_metric.reset_states()

            if epoch > 0:
                self.generator1.save(self.real_path + self.model_folder + "\\" + "gen_{}_Model1.h5".format(epoch))
                self.generator2.save(self.real_path + self.model_folder + "\\" + "gen_{}_Model2.h5".format(epoch))
                self.generator3.save(self.real_path + self.model_folder + "\\" + "gen_{}_Model3.h5".format(epoch))

   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aut = MIMO_Model()
    aut.train(epochs=201, batch_size=2, sample_interval=5)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have removed the code which are made to save intermediate images results

Comment: please concentrate on init, train and train_step functions